# Issues with Background Larger than Circle Div CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, react-slick

I try to customize dots with React Slick and have this issue with the background color.
Here is how I set the styles.

```
 .slick-dots.circle-dots {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;
    .slick-active {
      background-color: red;
      background-size: contain;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  }
```

An this is the result. The background is actually larger than the circle with `border-radius: 50%`. As there dots are placed next to each other, it's easy to point out that one is bigger than the others and it's weird. Is there any way that I can fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since `.slick-active` is a child of `.slick-dots.circle-dots`, setting

```
 .slick-dots.circle-dots {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    //hide anything that spans larger than the element 
    .slick-active {
      background-color: red;
      background-size: contain;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  }
```

to hide overflows could work

Comment: I have figured out the issue. For this, I use the `CustomPaging` to create these dots, thus, I have a component called `Dot` as my customized dot. The `.slick-active` is a div that wrap the component `Dot`, so if I set color for `.slick-active`, the background will always be bigger than the `Dot`. The solution is to target the child div `.slick-active {
      div {
        background: red;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-size: contain;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    }`
Thanks a lot. Your answer is a hint for me to solve this problem.

Comment: Glad to help :)